# Implication of $(a,b,c)[a,b,c]=abc$

Tags: number-theory

I'm working on number theory out of Niven and I've come to a problem I'm not sure how to attack.

If $(a,b,c)[a,b,c]=abc$, then $(a,b)=(b,c)=(a,c)=1$

This is basically saying that all 3 numbers are co-prime.  We are also given that the minimum of prime powers of $a,b,c$ plus the maximum of prime powers of $a,b,c$ yields the product $abc$.  This makes intuitive sense to me, but now to apply this to the gcd of two of three of the numbers is not immediately apparent.

Something I do know is that $((a,b),c)=(a,b,c)$, but again, not sure how this is helping me.

Comment: I know that $(a, \ldots)$ is greatest common divisor, but what is $[a, \ldots]$?

Comment: Yes, lowest common multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\displaystyle a = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{i_p}$, $\displaystyle b = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{j_p}$, and $\displaystyle c = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{k_p}$.  Then $\displaystyle (a,b,c) = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{\min\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}}$ and $\displaystyle [a,b,c] = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{\max\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}}$.

Hence $\displaystyle (a,b,c)[a,b,c] = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{\min\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}+\max\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}}$ and $\displaystyle abc = \prod_{p\text{ is prime}}p^{i_p+j_p+k_p}$.  This means $\min\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}+\max\{i_p,j_p,k_p\} = i_p+j_p+k_p$.  Suppose for some prime $p$, we have $0<i_p$.  What are the possibilities for $j_p,k_p$?  If either $j_p=0$ or $k_p=0$, then $\min\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}=0$.  That implies $\max\{i_p,j_p,k_p\} = i_p+j_p+k_p$.  Can you show that equality holds if and only if $j_p=k_p=0$?  Next, if both $j_p>0$ and $k_p>0$, then without loss of generality, we have $0<i_p\le j_p\le k_p$, so $\min\{i_p,j_p,k_p\}+\max\{i_p,j_p,k_p\} = i_p+k_p \neq i_p+j_p+k_p$, so it cannot be that both $j_p>0$ and $k_p>0$.  That leaves only the possibility that both are zero.  That shows $(a,b)=(a,c)=1$, and a similar argument shows $(b,c)=1$.

Comment: I had the idea that the product of two numbers equaling the product of three numbers was going to yield something similar.  I thought that the min + max argument was going to be a deadend and didn't try it.  Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\rm\ ABC = (A,B,C)[A,B,C].\ $ Let $\rm\ d = (A,B,C),\,\ A = da,\ B = db,\ C = dc.$

So above is $\rm\ abcd^3\! = d[da,db,dc] = d^2[a,b,c],\ $ so $\rm\ abcd = [a,b,c],\,$ so $\rm\ d=1\,$ by $\rm\,[a,b,c]\mid abc.$

If $\rm\ e\mid b,c\ $ then $\rm\ a,b,c\mid abc/e\,\Rightarrow\,[a,b,c]=abc\mid abc/e\,\Rightarrow\, e = 1.\,$ Hence $\rm\,(b,c) = 1.$

Therefore $\rm\,(B,C) = (db,dc) = d(b,c) = 1\cdot 1.\,$ By symmetry $\rm\,(A,B)=1=(C,A).\ \ $ **QED**